# Will it require me to use VBA if I want to 'copy/paste' data in workbook 2 after being entered into workbook 1?

Tags: excel, data-entry, vba

I have started to build a couple of workbooks that I would like to communicate with each other. My goal is to take entries from column1 @ midnight,6am,noon, 6pm, and 11pm in workbook1 and 'copy/paste' them to row1 with the same labels in workbook 2. My main question is do I need VBA for this? My research leads me to believe that I do. However, I know that if I am doing this between spreadsheets in the same workbook I don't. I just use code such as ='Sht1'!A1 on spreadsheet 2 and it will copy and paste that entry from spreadsheet 1, so is there a similar way to do so with workbooks? Thanks for any input!

Comment: If you want to automate this process, then VBA is the preferred method. It's possible to use `INDIRECT` or linked cells, but I'm not sure that would get you what you want.

Comment: @pnuts, I tried to use this function ='[May 2018]4th'!$C$13:$D$13 and =[May 2018]'4th'!$C$13:$D$13, but I get a #Value! with both. It prompts me to open the file, I click on the file and the reference point, but then gives me that #Value! error message. Any thoughts?

Comment: @PeterT, thank you for the input. I will research INDIRECT and linked cells.

Comment: @PeterT, I have found some websites that give INDEX as the function to call for this reference, but I am having trouble with it. Now I am getting a #REF! error instead of the #VALUE! error. This is my code:

=INDEX('[May 2018.xlsm]1st'!$C:$C,13,3)

I have done slight variations that come to the same conclusion.

Comment: @PeterT, I have run into a reference problem, but I can not figure out the solution. I used the formula below to reference data and it works. Every time. However, when I try to move onto the next months spreadsheet and use the same formula, calling for the correct month I am getting 0.00 as my entry, so:

=INDEX('[May2018.xlsm]1st'!A13:$C$13, 1, 3) works and references the entered number (say 150)



BUT: 

 =INDEX('[June 2018.xlsx]1st'!A19:D19,1,3) doesn't work. Do I have a syntax error that I am over looking?

Comment: What happens when you run the same `INDEX` formula from inside the "June 2018.xlsx" workbook? (delete filename part so it looks like `=INDEX(1st!A19:D19,1,3)`) If that works, then it suggests there's a problem with the filename. Other than that, this is difficult to figure without the actual workbooks.

Comment: Ok, I ran it with no file name and it produced the same result. Fair enough on the tough to solve part. Any thoughts on where to look?

Comment: If you placed that formula in a cell within the "June" workbook and it had the same result, then I suggest it's a problem with the data itself.

Comment: Figured out my issue with that one. Apparently, unless I am doing something wrong which is possible, INDEX will not update the cell once an entry is made/changed. So, I guess this is not the best function to use with a template and an unused spreadsheet.

Comment: @PeterT, I used a link via the Shift, Ctrl, and Enter method and now it is updating and I also switched to SUM function, which works for some reason. I'm basically self teaching, so IDK why or what the reasons for any of this stuff working are LOL

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. INDEX function was correct, at least in this instance. The correct formula was not far off because I had my row and column messed up, so the answer was:

=INDEX('[May 2018.xlsm]1st'!$A$13:$D13,1,3)

To break it down for people that do not want to use VBA and struggle with coding like me :)

INDEX() is my function

'[May 2018.xlsm]1st'! is the name of the workbook and sheet that I want to reference and ! means that the workbook is macro-enabled

$A$13 is the beginning of my range (A,13)

$D$13 is the end of my range (D,13)

So my range is 1 row and 4 columns (Think of it like a table), yours could be whatever you want (2x4 or 6x6 or whatever size you need)

1 is the row in the range that I want to reference

3 is the column in the range that I want reference

Be sure to close the function with )

I turned out making this more complicated than it should have been, because I had merged cells and I was technically referencing the right row, but not the right column. I was using (1,2) as my row and column which was referencing my first cell.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: I found later that this only works for referencing static data, so if you use it for a template or another spreadsheet that gets updates, this is not the answer for that situation. I will update again if I figure it out.

EDIT 2: For this to work with a updating spreadsheet, do the following.

=('[June''18 7Q10.xlsm]1st'!$C$13:$D$13)

Its actually much simpler to perform than I originally made it out, but going back to my beginner programming classes I wanted to make sure I understand why it worked not only how to perform it.

The process via LINK is:

Open both workbooks (Source workbook = 1 and Updated = 2)

Find the cell you want to have the data 'Pasted' TO in (2) and edit it with =(.

Now go to (1) and click the cell the that you want to 'Copy' data FROM. This will generate a reference point for you.

Now go back to (2) and finish the function out by closing the argument with ).

Finally, simultaneously press Shift, Control, and Enter and the spreadsheets/workbooks will link, likely leaving you with your result or a 0.0 until data is updated.